# proving there many not be a fixed point

Tags: general-topology

For each positive integer $n$ let $f_n$ be a continuous function of $[0,1]$ into itself and let $a \in [0,1]$ be such that $f_n(a) = a$, for all $n$. Further let $f$ be a continuous function of $[0,1]$ into itself. If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $(C[0,1],d)$ where $d(f,g) = \int^1_0 |f-g|dx$. Show that $a$ is not a fixed point of $f$.

Can you please give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: This is obviously false.

Comment: It should read $a$ is not *necessarily* a fixed point of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following function. 
$$
f_n(x) = 0 \mbox{ if } x\leq 1-\frac{1}{n}  
$$
and
$$
f_n(x) = n\left(x-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \mbox{ if } x> 1-\frac{1}{n}
$$
Note that $f_n(1)=1$ for all $n$. Now consider 
$$
f(x) = 0 \mbox{ for all }x\in [0,1].
$$
Notice that $f_n\rightarrow f$ under the metric you described. However, $1$ is not a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Notice that this was done with a carefully constructed example; the general claim is false, because there may well be a fixed point.